# Publish on user's wall as fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've created a Fan Page and I want to post on my fan's wall.
For this, I've created an application and I've got access_token for each user with publish_stream permission.

Now when I try to post something on one of my fan's(Mr. X) wall... It published as Mr. X not as my Fan page or me? It shows that MR. X has written on his wall...

Plese tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Let me get this straight, you want to publish on the wall of your page fans using a facebook application?

Comment: YES. I pulled all the information on my fans.They've authenticate my application. I just want to write on their wall as MY FAN PAGE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is posting using the USER's access token.  You need to use a PAGE access token for that.  Please read the authentication documentation on how to get a PAGE access token.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Still not able to do this.... I just want my page to write on a user's wall..... It's very urgent.. Please help me...

Comment: To post on the users walls (of those who have liked a fan page), you need to post to the page's own wall (since the fans like the page, they will see the post on their feed).  Posting directly to a fan's feed is prohibited.